# How people can create website link preview?

Tags: html

I'm wondering how to do people do this with their site?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wpmK.png I would like to do this with my site but I'm very confused. Thanks!

Comment: This is mostly done with meta tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Website title to display</title>
        <meta name="description" content="The description you want to display">
    </head>
</html>
```

You need to use meta tags. To read more about meta tags, go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp